# Loop filling a set with logging

Tags: python, functional-programming, file-system, windows, logging

After watching [Raymond Hettinger](https://twitter.com/raymondh)s talk [Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go) I got back to a function I wrote.

I'm not quite sure how to make it more pythonic but I think this might be a use-case to use the [map function](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map).

```
import logging
import string
import os

def _mounted_drives(possible_device_letters=string.ascii_uppercase):
    """Returns a set of mounted drive letters on a Windows machine."""
    result = set()
    for letter in possible_device_letters:
        mounted = os.path.exists(letter + ':')
        if mounted:
            logging.info('Found device ' + letter)
            result.add(letter)

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(_mounted_drives())
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a leading underscore in the function name. By convention, a leading underscore would indicate that it is a private member of a class.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the logging and using [set comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) :

```
def _mounted_drives(possible_device_letters=string.ascii_uppercase):
    return {l for l in possible_device_letters if os.path.exists(l + ':')}
```

If you do want the logging but you do not care about it being done once every device is found :

```
def _mounted_drives(possible_device_letters=string.ascii_uppercase):
    s = {l for l in possible_device_letters if os.path.exists(l + ':')}
    for l in s:
        logging.info('Found device ' + l)
    return s
```